# how to move dashboard button to website menu if possible wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want an easier way for our clients to get to the dashboard, please see the screenshot for reference Thanks.

http://prntscr.com/kzoz4x

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You must provide code that you have tried in order to get help here.  Please provide the code in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your functions.php to add Dashboard link in your admin bar

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_second_dashboard_link', 999 );

function toolbar_second_dashboard_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'second-dashboard-link',
        'title' => 'Dashboard',
        'href'  => 'mysite.com/wp-admin/',
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-toolbar-page' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

Result - http://joxi.ru/Y2Lz1yOt9GKd9r